# Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected in Laravel

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I am new in React. I am using React in Laravel. I am trying to learn SPA using React in Laravel from this [tutorial.](https://www.binaryboxtuts.com/php-tutorials/how-develop-a-react-single-page-application-spa-in-laravel-8/#Step_6_Create_The_React_Files)

I got an error Warning:

```
React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Main`.
    at Main
```

Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share your `Main` component?

Comment: @apokryfos I did exactly same as the link in the tutorial. https://www.binaryboxtuts.com/php-tutorials/how-develop-a-react-single-page-application-spa-in-laravel-8/#Step_6_Create_The_React_Files